# WARN log metricbeat pods (on kubernetes) : DNS lookup failure "k8s-node4": lookup k8s-node4 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host

Tags: kubernetes, warnings, metricbeat

I install metricbeat via official helm charts (default value).

But, inside log files I observed that :

kubectl -n logging logs metricbeat-metricbeat-ljjfx :

```
2019-10-20T10:22:57.191Z    WARN    transport/tcp.go:53 DNS lookup failure "k8s-node4": lookup k8s-node4 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
2019-10-20T10:23:01.196Z    WARN    transport/tcp.go:53 DNS lookup failure "k8s-node4": lookup k8s-node4 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
2019-10-20T10:23:02.143Z    WARN    transport/tcp.go:53 DNS lookup failure "k8s-node4": lookup k8s-node4 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
2019-10-20T10:23:03.867Z    WARN    transport/tcp.go:53 DNS lookup failure "k8s-node4": lookup k8s-node4 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
2019-10-20T10:23:06.364Z    WARN    transport/tcp.go:53 DNS lookup failure "k8s-node4": lookup k8s-node4 on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
```

Answer (score 1):

Using helm3, enabling **hostNetwork** in values.yml solved the problem

```
daemonset:
  enabled: true
  hostNetworking: true
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error indicates that you should look into your DNS policy. More details can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy). In short, you need this config to be added:

```
hostNetwork: true  
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
```

Please let me know if that helped.